# How to install Framework 3.5 uniquely to all OS from .Net Setup Prerequisite?

Tags: .net, windows-8, frameworks, windows-8.1, setup-project

I made setup for WPF application which i developed with Framework 3.5. I made setup (through .Net Setup & Deployment Project) with dotNetFx35setup.exe as Prerequisite for application.

Suppose i run this setup in XP its working fine as i can able to run framework setup if didn't previously installed in XP. But same setup if i run to Windows 8/8.1 then dotNetFx35setup.exe not working. its ask me to download online & install or i can install offline through Dism.exe.

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sxs /LimitAccess
```

can this Dism.exe command work to all OS from xp to windows 10? is there any unique way to make setup which install framework 3.5?

Please suggest the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no uniquely way to install .net 3.5. The .net 3.5 Installer works for XP/Vista, starting with Windows 7 it is part of Windows. Here you can activate it with DISM. Starting with Windows 8, Microsoft declared .net 3.5 obsolete and made it an optional feature.

To avoid this hassle, upgrade the solution to .Net 4.0 and include the 4.0 Installer in XP/Vista/7 and for Windows 8/10 you don't need to do anything, they include .Net 4.x already.

Comment: I understood what you are saying and aware of this but project which am working is ERP. This ERP project having other frameworks like CSLA & Prism. So if i am going to convert whole ERP to 4.0 it takes time (may be 2-4 months) which practically i can't do that.

Comment: can we do one thing instead of Prerequisite, can we handle this in Custom Action? In custom action we check the version of OS and decide whether installer need to run or DISM command need to run?

Comment: yes, OS version detection + setup .net 3.5 the correct way (DISM or dotNetFx35setup.exe) would be the only way.